# ¿Cómo hacer que un JFrame bloqué un método hasta hacer click en un botón?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un JFrame, este es de una ventana donde de podrá escribir cierto codigo(Es un tipo de lenguaje mio), lo que quiero hacer es que se ejecute un método, este lanzará el JFrame y regresará el codigo escrito por el usuario en forma de String.

El problema es que la forma en que lo hago solo funciona imprimiendo una variable a la consola:

```
public String edit() {
    code.setText(text);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
    while(!done) {
        System.out.println(done);
    }
    done = false;
    setVisible(false);
    String cod = code.getText();
    code.setText("");
    return cod;
}
```

Este codigo si funciona, el problema es que imprime la variable "done" en la pantalla, cosa que no quiero, sin embargo si en vez de

```
System.out.println(done);
```

dejo

```
;
```

El boton no funciona.

Aquí la clase completa(Estoy aprendiendo a usar Swing):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ScriptEditor extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JTextArea code;
private JButton button;

private boolean done = false;

public ScriptEditor() {
    setLayout(null);
    code = new JTextArea();
    button = new JButton("Terminar");
    code.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    button.setBounds(0, 500, 500, 30);
    add(code);
    add(button);
    setBounds(0,0,520,570);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
}

public String edit(String text) {
    code.setText(text);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
    while(!done) {
        System.out.println(done);
    }
    done = false;
    setVisible(false);
    String cod = code.getText();
    code.setText("");
    return cod;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    done = true;
}

}
```

Se supone que hay un objeto de ScriptEditor, de este se llama edit(str) con el str el codigo que ya existia(si ya existía uno).

Quizá un loop while no sea la mejór opción pero no se me ocurrió otra cosa(Pense en wait(), pero es el mismo Thread).

Si hay una opción que no implique un ciclo while sería estupendo.

Por cierto:
Cuando está System.out.println(done); en el loop, al dar click al botón, este hace lo que debe.

Cuando no está, al dar click a boton la ventana ni si quiera se cierra(no sale del loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te he malinterpretado, lo que quieres hacer es un [cuadro de diálogo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuadro_de_di%C3%A1logo) *modal* para introducir o editar un código.

#### ❏ El código

Si este es el caso, entonces el camino a seguir es utilizar un [`javax.swing.JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) con un [`javax.swing.JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).

Y como al parecer deseas utilizar esta funcionalidad varias veces, entonces conviene ponerla en un método, como si de una *utileria* se tratara, esto es:

```
public static String showMessage(Component parent, String title, String content) {
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.setFont(new Font("Consolas", 0, 10));
    area.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    area.setText(content);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
    pane.setViewportView(area);
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, pane, title, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    return area.getText();
}
```

#### ❏ Modo de uso

Con esto, para introducir un código nuevo, basta con:

```
String code = showMessage(null, "Input code", null);
```

[image: captura]

Y para editar un código existente, entonces:

```
String edited = showMessage(null, "Edit code", code);
```

Comment: Gracias! Si me entendiste, justamente lo que necesitaba.